# Custom ActionBar with Transparent Background

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar, transparent

I'm not able to get transparent Background for actionbar.Here is my code.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/action_bar_theme</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

<style name="action_bar_theme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/action_bar_title</item>
</style>
```

I'm not able to get transparent background. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong or whether i'v missed sumthing.

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mActionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mActionBar.setSplitBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.login_title));

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView,
                             new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                                     ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                     Gravity.CENTER
                             )
    );

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the **Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar** which is defined in support library, the android:xxx attr is unavalabile. For your probelm, just remove the prefix **android:** of `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/action_bar_theme</item>` and `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>`.

By the way, check other android:xxx attr in your xml file for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom hexcolor in your resource

```
<color name="custom_color">#8C000000</color>
```

Then refer like this

```
<item name="android:background">@color/custom_color></item>
```

---

Sample Hex Color Code : #8C000000.

The above sample color will show black with 55% of transparency

I think this will help you.

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Tell me if it works.

**Solution 2:**

*For Android 3.0 and higher only*

If your minSdkVersion is set to 11 or higher, your custom theme should use Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For Android 2.1 and higher

If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on devices running versions lower than Android 3.0, your custom theme should use Theme.AppCompat theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Ref:https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html